# I want to generate a daily wise summary report (combine report) from these tables data like below order

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, report

I have 3 tables Products , Purchase , purchase_detail ,  Sale, Sale_detail .
Sale or purchase tables join with their detail tables on PurchaseId or SaleId as foreign key.
Similarly Product table join with detail tables with ProductId, 
So I want to generate a  daily wise summary report (combine report) from these tables data like below order..

1. Itemcode Purchaseqty  Pprice    Pdate      Saleqty Sprice   Sdate
2. 4NOK       10         1000   2014/12/12      20       12     2014/12/12

If  same item sale and purchase on same date then should shown it record in one row and if only purchase or sale then should shown in separate rows  and  other colums will be remain empty,
And rows  will be repeated for an item  when date changed, and items should be shown in sequance according date.
But My current query not showing my desire  report,

```
SELECT A.ProdId, A.ProdName, A.ItemCode,B.PurchaseDate,B.PQty,
 B.PurchasePrice,NULL SaleDate ,NULL SQty, NULL SalePrice
FROM  Products A FULL OUTER JOIN vPurchaseSummary B ON A.ProdId = B.ItemId   
WHERE B.ItemId IS NOT NULL AND B.PurchaseDate BETWEEN '2012-12-12' AND '2015-12-12'

UNION 

SELECT A.ProdId, A.ProdName, A.ItemCode, NULL,NULL,NULL,C.SaleDate,C.SQty, C.SalePrice
FROM  Products A FULL OUTER JOIN vSaleSummary C ON A.ProdId = C.ItemId
WHERE C.ItemId IS NOT NULL AND C.SaleDate BETWEEN '2012-12-12' AND '2015-12-12'

ORDER BY PurchaseDate
```

[image]

sorry my english is not good.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What if there are two purchases and one sale of the same item on the same date?   Then what?

Comment: check now i update it , in the above image Nokia X1  purchase on 10/11/2015 and sale also on 10/11/2015 , but shwon in different rows i want to show this in single row

Comment: I have an answer, but it will only work if there can never be more than one sale and one purchase of the same item on the same date.

Comment: no there may be more than one sale and one purchase of same item on same date but we combine it in single one by sum of qty and sum of price and one date also